# Python Pandas Dataframe XML

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I am fairly new to python and am looking for some guidance on my python code. I have multiple XML files that I would like to put into ONE data frame. Each XML file is one record. My code below puts the data into multiple data frames but am trying to find a solution to append the rows to one data frame. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my existing code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import pandas as pd 
import os    
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 

path = '/app/notebooks'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.xml'):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(fullname, "r"), "xml")
        d = {}
        for tag in soup.RECORDING.find_all(recursive=False):
            d[tag.name] = tag.get_text(strip=True)
        df = pd.DataFrame([d])
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        display (pd.DataFrame(df))
```

Current output: 2 data frames but I'm trying to output 1 data frame with 2 records
[image]

Comment: Either create an empty dataframe then append to it in a loop, or append the individual dataframes to a list and then merge them after the loop completes

Comment: Thank you! That answered my question.

Comment: In that case I'll suggest this be closed as a duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101), glad I could help!

Comment: Do note: in forthcoming Pandas v1.3 (to release May 31, 2021) has a new method: [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/io.html#io-read-xml). If XML is fairly flat, it can easily parse content to data frame. If not, use stylesheet via `lxml` to run XSLT to flatten for import. No loops needed!